# How to access webform field labels in a twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

The YAML below represents a webform. Theming is simple using the twig template also found below, but the label for email is inline with the input field by default. How can the labels in the webform be accessed through twig for further theming?

**Webform YAML**

```
name:
  '#title': Name
  '#type': textfield
  '#required': true
  '#default_value': '[current-user:display-name]'
email:
  '#title': Email
  '#type': email
  '#required': true
  '#default_value': '[current-user:mail]'
subject:
  '#title': Subject
  '#type': textfield
  '#required': true
  '#test': 'Testing contact webform from [site:name]'
message:
  '#title': Message
  '#type': textarea
  '#required': true
  '#test': 'Please ignore this email.'
actions:
  '#type': webform_actions
  '#title': 'Submit button(s)'
  '#submit__label': 'Send message'
```

**webform--contact.html.twig**

```
<div class="container">
    <form{{ attributes }}>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ element.elements.name }}
            {{ element.elements.email }}
            {{ element.elements.subject }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ element.elements.message }}
            {{ element.form_token }}
            {{ element.form_build_id }}
            {{ element.form_id }}
            {{ element.elements.actions }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your last comment:

> Well that isn't very intuitive. It would be nice to just access
>   everything directly in the twig template.

OK, then try different templates:

When the form theme wrapper is executed the inside of the wrapper is already rendered in `{{ children }}`. Don't try to render the form again, use this template only for the form tag and the outside container:

**webform--contact.html.twig**

```
<div class="container">
   <form{{ attributes }}>
   {{ title_prefix }}
   {{ children }}
   {{ title_suffix }}
   </form>
</div>
```

Use for the inside of the form the #theme template itself:

**webform-submission-form--contact.html.twig**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        {{ form.name }}
        {{ form.email }}
        {{ form.subject }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        {{ form|without('name', 'email', 'subject') }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Finally you can theme the form element in **form-element--webform-email.html.twig**

Comment: For webform 6.2, I had to add it as `{{ form['elements']['full_name'] }}` to get the fields, Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

you are very close !

all you need to do is this

```
<label>
  {{ element.elements.name["#title"] }}
</label>

// just run to get all possible element, array values  {{ dump(element.elements.email) }}
```

Comment: This works, although the label is printing twice now. Tried to see what other variables are available by using the dump function that you provided. But it doesn't print or render anything.

Comment: Was able to turn debugging on and see the dump output, but I can't seem to find the correct variable for the form input. ["#input"] is just a boolean that prints "1" (true).

Comment: no all that stuff is the render array, you cant get an straight up html input from this array 
you should look into creating a pre possessor to make new array or pass what you need to the template, @see template_preprocess_webform()

Comment: Well that isn't very intuitive. It would be nice to just access everything directly in the twig template.

Answer (score 0):

Create a tempalte

```
webform-submission-form--{webform_machine_name}.html.twig 
Ex. webform-submission-form--contact-us.html.twig

{{ form.elements.field_machine_name }}
Ex. {{ form.elements.your_name }}
    {{ form.elements.email_address }}

    {{ form.elements.actions }}
    {{ form.form_build_id }}
    {{ form.form_token }}
    {{ form.form_id }}
```

Make sure that you added also form_token, form_build_id and form_id

```
    {{ form.form_build_id }}
    {{ form.form_token }}
    {{ form.form_id }}
```